# Class Design Within VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

-Edit- This is for a finance API I am designing. I am in the process of creating some empty classes, getting a feel for the general structure. My primary concern is designing a pleasant user experience without requiring a manual to explain how to use it. -End Edit-

I have been scratching my head trying to think of the best way to go about designing a specific class. I will create a *general example* to illustrate.

```
Namespace SomeNamespace 
    Public Class Results
        Public a1 as Integer
        Public a2 as Integer
        ...
        Public b1 as Integer
        ...
        Public z1 as Integer
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The example above is generic, but the point is there are many values within the class. The letter in the variable name represents a similar group of results. The "a" results are similar, "b" similar, etc. I had thought to make a class for each type of result value (since they are a type of result, but separate concepts from each other) within the Results class such as...

```
Public Class Results
    Class a 
        Public a1 as Integer
    End Class
    Class b ... End Class
End Class
```

The problem with this is that it is not explicit that when a person uses the class

```
Dim ResultObject as new SomeNamespace.Results.a()
```

the Results object would have to be instantiated first, because any of the sub-classes a,b, etc would rely on the Results object. But the user would see the objects a,b, etc and perhaps not know that they must create the parent object first.

I thought about making the classes separate and each constructor would create a Result object, but that seems backwards logically. Any Advice? Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: what?? you need an `IEnumerable` or a `Dictionary` of whatever thing you want to store. Having public propertyA, propertyB, propertyC... all the way to Z, with the same type, is the worst design ever.

Comment: If I was dumb enough to actually design it as such, I wouldn't have wasted my time asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make an Abstract class Result and create an inheritance structure ResultTypeA, ResultTypeB etc.? With no details on the problem it is really hard to give a meaningfull answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a single 2-dimensional integer array, where the first index is the result class (i.e. letter 'a' or 'b' etc), and the second index is the result number (i.e. a1 or z2 etc)?

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately I am less concerned about how to get the data or how to store it and more concerned with proper OOP class design. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Two quick recommendations.

1) In classes, don't expose your fields. Only expose methods and properties. If you're using auto implemented properties this is done by just adding the Property keyword in your declaration. Otherwise, declare your field as private and the property that exposes it as public:

```
Public Class Foo
   Private _V1 As Integer  ' Backing field
   Public Property V2 As Integer ' Auto Property
   Public Property V1 As Integer ' With backing field
       Get
           Return _V1
       End Get
       Set (Value as Integer)
           _V1 = value
       End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

2) Don't nest your class declarations. Instead of

```
Public Class Results
    Class a 
        Public a1 as Integer
    End Class
    Class b ... End Class
End Class
```

Do the following:

```
Public Class Results
  Public Property A1 As A
  Public Property B1 As B
End Class
Public Class A
  Public Property A1 As Integer
End Class
Public Class B
  Public Property B1 As Integer
End Class
```

For naming conventions, you should name your properties as nouns and methods as verbs. I regarding your ordering question, I recommend starting with the category (noun) and then adding adjectives after it in increasingly specific terms:

```
  Property NameFirst As String
  Property NameLast As String
  Property ContactEmail As String
  Property ContactPhoneHome As String
  Property ContactPhoneWork As String
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for your response. I greatly appreciate the time you spent on that!